# post input data to codeigniter controller from outside codeigniter folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am facing a problem. I have a normal html files (contact.html) in cpanel's public_html folder. And admin panel which is developed in CodeIgniter. Now what i am trying to do is print or receive input data from contact.html file to codeigniter controller. Below mention the code

contact.html

```
<html>
  <form name ="userinput" action="admin/index.php/contact/contact" method="post">
  <div class="row contact-form">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
  <input type="text" name="yourname" id="yourname" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
   </div><!-- end col -->
  </div><!-- end row -->
 </form>
```

controller : contact.php

```
<?php
class Contact extends CI_Controller
{
  function contact()
   {
   echo 'test';
   echo $yourname = $this->input->post('yourname');
   }
 }?>
```

now when i am submitting data 'test' is printing but i can not get the post data of textbox.
The error is mention below.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Contact::$input

Filename: controllers/contact.php

Line Number: 12

please help me how will i get it.

Comment: you need to create a function named contact in your contact controller

Comment: yes i have already created the function.. but dont know wy it is not showing it.. let me edit @Poria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  class Contact extends CI_Controller
  {
    public function contact(){
    echo 'test';
    echo $yourname = $this->input->post('yourname');
    $this->load->view('index');  // put this file in application/views/index.php  ,also rename to .php
   }
  }
 ?>
```

Try creating the function in your controller. Hope it helps !

Comment: try using $_POST['yourname'];die; instead of $this->input->post('yourname');

Comment: The problem is contact.html file is not inside the codeignigter folder. inside public_html there is folder admin inside that there is CI, Outside admin folder contact.html file is present. that is why i am facing the problem. so ci is not getting $this->input->post('yourname')

Comment: you need to put the index.html file inside the folder application/views

Comment: application/views/index.php  also rename the file to .php extension

Comment: $_POST['yourname']; is working but getting an warning like A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Home' does not have a method 'show_404'

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 360

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111287/discussion-between-poria-and-manish-sasmal).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a index function or another function

File name: Contact.php file name and class should have only first letter upper case with controllers and models.

```
<?php

class Contact extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() {

   $yourname = $this->input->post('yourname');
   echo $yourname;

   // Since you had named the view file with a .html you need to add .html
   $this->load->view('contact.html');

   }

}
```

If you name your view files with .php instead of a .html

```
$this->load->view('contact');
```

I would autoload the [url helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) on autoload.php and would look into [form helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: hi i have already written this function. i edited my question . please check. The problem is contact.html file is not inside the codeignigter folder. inside public_html there is folder admin inside that there is CI, Outside admin folder contact.html file is present. that is why i am facing the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that since your function name is same as class name that it's treating it as constructor. Rename your function to something else, update your action link in form and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Better try native PHP way of getting value

```
echo $_POST['yourname'];
```

Hope this helps